# apache2: why all subdomains redirect to www?

Tags: apache-2.2, http

I have `NameVirtualHost *:80` in `ports.conf` and a `VirtualHost` who has `ServerName www.mysite.com` in my conf file.
I also have few subdomains mapped to other VirtualHosts.

Currently if I access `mysite.com` with some arbitrarily picked subdomain that is not configured as a subdomain in my config file, it redirects to the one with `www.`. For example, if i try `nowhere.mysite.com` it goes to `www.mysite.com`.

I don't think this is normal behavior on a web site. How can I ignore all requests that does not go to any proper domain?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, first, the fact that those names resolve at all instead of kicking the user back an error with name resolution implies that you've configured a wildcard in your DNS zone (`*.mysite.com.`).  If you want lookups to bogus subdomains to fail, get rid of that.

On a name-based virtual host, the first virtual host to load on the address:port combination is treated as the default, and handles all requests for hostnames that aren't configured.  You can see how this shakes out for your installation with `apachectl -S`.

Apache will never send a redirect `30x` response putting the user on a different domain name unless it's configured to do so - the redirecting behavior you're seeing is either explicitly configured or being generated by the application running on your web server.  Normally, you'd just be getting content served by the default virtual host, not getting redirected to its canonical name.

If you don't want to get rid of the wildcard DNS but do want to serve up errors for these requests, then change the load order of your virtual hosts to have the default be something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName catchall
  <Location />
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: It seems like I cant use `Order` in `VirtualHost`

Comment: @thkang You're right, my mistake.  Fixed.

Comment: okay, so it seems like I have a wildcard in my DNS, through my domain registrar - and it have to be kept that way. the `<Location>` tags were kinda meaningless because apache is just a middlemen between wsgi  and user, as I have a `WSGIScriptAlias` sitting on `/`. But thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: @thkang So then your `WSGIScriptAlias` configuration is global?  If you don't want that active for all virtual hosts, then move it to within the virtual hosts you want it to be active for.

Comment: nah, WSGIScriptAlias is on the first `VirtualHost` whose servername is `www.mysite.com`

Answer (score 3):

If the domain www.mysite.com is the first domain defined in your configuration then this is entirely normal. If Apache cannot match the domain in the Host: header to a virtual host [ServerName](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#servername) or [ServerAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#serveralias) it will serve the contents of the default domain which unless otherwise defined is the first one.

You should probably read the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) it is immensely helpful.